# audio stream duration in ios

Tags: ios, audio

I'm using AVAudioPlayer for playing audio stream(download stream into buffer and play it).
I need to know how to disable reading some id3 tags by AVAudioPlayer class, because i need duration of loaded data, not all-file duration. Or maybe someone know how to get duration of loaded data.
PS. Buffer filling while playing.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code to get the duration.

```
// get the URL of the sound file to be played
    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath ] options:nil];
    // get the duration of sound to be played in seconds 
    CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
```

Following imports may be required:

1)    `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

2) CoreMedia framework for CMTime

Comment: Thank for answering, but it is not what i want. In my program I fave buffer with audio data. And i need to know duration of data, that stored in buffer. Only duration of stored data, not duration of all track.

Comment: Buffer filling while playing. So, i need to know how many seconds i can play from buffer now, and after some time, etc...

Comment: For buffer i use NSMutableData.